# How to add multiple apiKey to OpenAPI Generator in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

Why I cannot use multiple apiKey securities with Kotlin generator? This is my spec:

```yaml
...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    Apikey:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: apikey
    Loginkey:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: loginkey
...
```

...and this is what I get in Kotlin:

```kotlin
import org.openapitools.client.auth.ApiKeyAuth
import org.openapitools.client.auth.ApiKeyAuth
```

Why there are two imports?

Comment: I think it's because both `Apikey` and `Loginkey` have the same type, `apiKey`. It's probably not intentional though, so I suggest opening an issue in the repo (I guess this one: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator)

Comment: @user3738870 thanks for the confirmation. Issue created: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/13394